# How to use PagingAndSortingRepository to sort by Ids passed in?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use PagingAndSortingRepository to query for a list but i want the results in the same order as the list passed in:

```
Page<Person> findByIdIn(List<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

I.e. if ids looks like

```
[4,2,3,1]
```

I'd like the results to return paginated and using that same order.
I'm definitely open to using different interfaces.

Comment: You are breaking the pagination contract between user and your app. The `Pageable` contains sort attribute that defines how the data needs to be ordered (for example ascending as requested by user) but you are trying to override it with your own ordering.

Comment: There seems to be a good solution here: stackoverflow.com/a/47042709/66686